# Retrieve Log's Thread in Logback Filter

Tags: logback

Using `ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3` I've added `TurboFilter` to the `LoggerContext` sniffing for all the logs that go through the loggers:

```
loggerContext.addTurboFilter(filter);
```

But I can't find a way to figure out the log `Thread`. It actually doesn't seem to be passed in to the `TurboFilter` function:

```
public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level, String format, Object[] params, Throwable t) {
}
```

Any suggestions how to get the whole info from the loggers including the Threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it wasn't so difficult at all. I figured it out that the `decide` method is called on the same `Thread` where the log has occurred, so `Thread.currentThread().getName()` gives the information I need.